# Windows and Apache Thrift Executable

Tags: python, windows, thrift

I am testing out how simple Apache Thrift is to learn and it looks promising. One major problem: the first tutorial doesn't work...

I have Windows 7, Python 2.7, and got the Thrift .exe for Windows v.0.9.1. I'd rather not compile from source as I don't use Cygwin etc. The exe gave the problems described below. So I moved on and tried using Chocolatey to install Thrift using
    cinst Thrift
which worked fine and gave me Thrift v0.9.0. But this version results in the same behavior as the exe, described below.

When I run the tutorial found at http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/py I get the following:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Thrift>thrift -r --gen py tutorial.thrift
[WARNING:C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Thrift/tutorial.thrift:59] Could not find include file shared.thrift

[ERROR:C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Thrift/tutorial.thrift:123] (last token was 'shared.SharedService')
Service "shared.SharedService" has not been defined.
```

Hopefully the exe works for someone because I'd love to avoid this requiring a build from source.

Comment: "*Hopefully the exe works*" - it does. It is only your assumption, that the EXE is the problem. This assumption is **wrong**, which can be proven easily by trying the Linux build, which behaves exactly the same. In general, you might reconsider your problem solving strategies. Instead of spending time being busy installing and downloading things, and finally blindly blaming one of the tools, you should try to address the real problem, which requires that you first try to *understand* what the problem is all about. Then try to solve it.

Comment: Can you argue with line two of my post? Tutorials are meant to be blindly followed **in order to understand**. If you want to learn about Thrift where do you start? The tutorial. Rather than correct my problem solving, perhaps you can take a look at http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/ . There is no reference to the files you mention in it and they don't come with the exe. Thank you for the suggestion that it is an IDL file I am missing though. Since this is tutorial 1 I haven't mastered reading error messages.

Comment: You blamed the EXE, and the EXE is not broken. Also the first message says it quite clearly: `tutorial.thrift:59] Could not find include file shared.thrift`. Look at line 59 and you'll find an `include` statement, right? Anyway, thanks again for the info, very helpful. I saw a number of people having a problem with that issue but never really figured out why.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the tutorial assumes you have a /tutorial folder with two .thrift files included in it. If you go the Windows EXE route and then build your tutorial.thrift file, you will **also need to add shared.thrift** which can be found in Git at https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=tutorial/shared.thrift

Save this file next to your tutorial.thrift file and you can proceed with the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
thrift -r --gen py tutorial.thrift
```

uses the `-r[recurse]` switch to automatically build a second, included IDL file `shared.thrift`. This `shared.thrift` file is located in the same folder as `tutorial.thrift` is. Because Thrift looks for included files based on the current folder, you have to explicitly call the Thrift compiler from that folder.

Assumed, your Thrift working copy is under C:\Thrift and the `thrift.exe` is reachable via search path, open a command prompt, navigate to that folder and enter the command again:

```
C:\> cd Thrift\tutorial
C:\Thrift\tutorial> thrift.exe -r --gen py tutorial.thrift
```

<sub>PS: The 0.9.0 is slightly outdated. The 0.9.1 is fine, the forthcoming release 0.9.2 will have even more improvements.</sub>

Comment: It looks like the real problem is that the tutorial isn't written with the exe-based install in mind. I think am missing files that would be included with a source build. There is no shared.thrift that I can find. Will have to try and download it somewhere and see if that gets me further.

Comment: Just took a guess at a URL and found https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=tutorial/shared.thrift . Building with this included solved the problem... It turns out the EXE comes without these files as you would expect but the tutorial didn't account for needing to download **both** files to follow it if you go the Windows exe route.

Comment: You're right, I just created a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2487) for this. Thanks for pointing this out.