# Couldn't find libtoolize command in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, thrift

I am trying to configure apache thrift and i have installed cygwin to be able run the bash scripts on windows and i have installed libtool package as well and i still seem to be getting an error message:

**couldn't find libtoolize!**

I have also tried this in the DOS prompt and the bash shell as well, although you cant un bash scripts in the DOS window. 
When I run a bash script. I would like some help with this please as I'm really interested in using the apache thrift platform.

Comment: what do you get when you execute: `which libtoolize`? Also what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: This does not exactly answer your question, but you don't have to use Cygwin/MinGW. There is a Visual Studio solution which you can use to compile the compiler, and you don't event need to do that: The compiler is [available for download as prebuilt EXE file](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.1/thrift-0.9.1.exe), see [Thrift download page](http://thrift.apache.org/download). For the libraries part, you use whatever environment you use normally: Windows & Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you follow the [Windows install from source](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/windows) steps and have you checked [this discussion how to install libtoolize on cygwin](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/how-to-install-libtoolize-td47374.html)?

Comment: i did install and download the EXE and although im pretty sure i didn't install it correctly. any ideas of how to use the exe and write the scripts.

Comment: yes, yes and yes to the JenG

Comment: when i try to enter a bash command in the git bash shell i do get command not found however this is also apparent when i attempt to execute a .sh script.

Comment: The EXE is a normal Windows EXE, to be used with the normal Windows command prompt. It is a command line tool that can be called with `-help` to get more information about all the options. For beginners, it is a good idea to follow the [Thrift tutorial](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/). Furthermore, you may want to have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163260/windows-and-apache-thrift-executable) as you may run into the same problem described there (look for `shared.thrift`).

Comment: You may also find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653240/what-is-rpc-framework-and-apache-thrift/20664706#20664706) helpful, as it points out some good sources of further, in-depth information regarding Apache Thrift.

Answer (score 1):

'libtoolize' is a part of libtool.
You can dowload latest version of libtool from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/, extract it, then run ./configure and make install from cygwin terminal.
This worked for me.